# sharingd wants to use the "Local Items keychain

Tags: password, permission, keychain, sharing

Every time after I log into my computer the first thing that happens is I get this message even if I put in the password. I can click it 3 times or so and it will go away, or I can give it the password but it will come back. I want to know what is sharingd? It looks like the terminal screen on the lock. Can anyone explain?[image: popup window asking for password]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What is `sharingd`?

`sharingd` is sharing daemon that enables AirDrop, Handoff, Instant Hotspot, Shared Computers, and Remote Disc in the Finder.

### How to solve asking for password problem?

I think the login password and the keychain are not the same. That's why you get those messages. You want your default keychain to be unlocked automatically when you log in. Synchronise your Keychain Access and account login passwords by doing this:

1. Open Keychain Access (you can get to it by choosing Utilities from the Go menu in the Finder).
2. From the Edit menu, choose Change Password for Keychain "login."
3. Type the former password of the account that you are currently logged in to, then click OK.
4. If you entered the correct password, a new window appears; enter the original password again in the Current Password field.
5. In the New Password field, type the password that matches your current account password.
6. Re-enter the newer password in the Verify field, then click OK.

Comment: For point 2: That is "choose the Keychan 'login' in the menu on the left before going for the menu bar.